# Telegram does not recognise account after being offline for almost a week due to battery failure

Tags: contacts, battery, sim-card, telegram, motorola-moto-g5

On Sunday, 13th September 2020, the battery of my Motorola Moto G5 broke down and I ordered a new one. Today, on Friday, 18th September 2020, it finally arrived and it works just fine. Several errors, however, occurred:

1. I have lost some of my contacts and only had the chance to recover some of them by importing an old VCF file that was not very up to date anymore. This, at least, brought back some contacts in WhatsApp. (Does anyone know why many of my contacts were lost after such an incident and some were not?)
2. But when I opened Telegram, I was asked to set up a new account. Even when I reinstalled Telegram, I am still asked to do this. I am, however, able to log on the [Telegram web app](https://web.telegram.org/). (Telegram sends me an SMS instead of an in-app text message.) There, I am able to see all the chats that are stored on Telegram’s cloud servers and also the contact names of people who are now not in my address book anymore, are displayed correctly. (Why is that? Is there a way to recover my address book via Telegram?)

What shall I do? **Can I just “re-register” at the Telegram app with my phone number and see my cloud chats again on my phone?** What error occurred there?

---

**Edit:** One thing just came to my mind. Can I just log off my phone via the web app and then just try to “register”/log on to my Telegram account via the Telegram app on my phone? Would this work and prevent data loss?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I was able to solve the problem. Telegram just logged me off the phone app. I was able to log back in and now I can use Telegram as before.